# How to get articleId dynamically?

Tags: liferay-6, article, assets, journal

I am using Asset Publisher and need to dynamically get the articleId of the latest journal article published.

I am using in **abstracts.jsp hook**:

```
version=JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestVersion(assetRenderer.getGroupId(), "14405");
journalArticle = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(assetRenderer.getGroupId() , "14405",version);
```

I have hardcoded the articleId here.
How do I avoid this??

Kindly help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dynamic query to get the latest Article from `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil` maybe you can use `ProjectionFactoryUtil.max("createDate");` to get the latest Date

```
DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class)  
  .add(ProjectionFactoryUtil.max("createDate"))  
  .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("groupId").eq(new Long(groupId)));  
List results =JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(query);`
```